# print XPath for match using xmlstarlet?

Tags: bash, xml, xpath

I would like to iterate over many xml files to fix outdated configuration entries by getting all matches and replacing then in a second step every entry by updated strings (multiline scripts in this case).
I'm aware how to query/select and print element's values using XPath with `xmlstarlet` e.g.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//hudson.tasks.Shell/command' $xml
```

or how to list all the XPaths using

```
xmlstarlet el -a $xml
```

Is there a way to output a list of valid *XPaths* expressions for every match to use this XPath string later to update the value in the second step? e.g.

```
maven2-moduleset/postbuilders/hudson.tasks.Shell[1]/command
maven2-moduleset/postbuilders/hudson.tasks.Shell[2]/command
```

The only solution I found for now was to count the paths from `el`output and then to loop over them by index (using bash).

Comment: For `xmlstarlet` you could try my own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72668093/14403369) at `stackoverflow.com`. For an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4747858 "Generate/get xpath from XML") SO answer.